# django logout and redirection

Tags: django, caching, logout

i am using django authentification to make a oneToone relation with the user table. I try to use decorator @login_required to the next page after the login. when i logout and click on the back button of firefox, i always go to the previous page even if @login_required is apply. but when i refresh it redirect me on the login page. Is it a cache problem? how can i solve it? I want to do it like how the administration works

```
def logout(request):
    from django.contrib.auth import logout
    from django.shortcuts import redirect
    logout(request)                    
    request.session.flush()
    return redirect('/')


from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
@login_required(login_url='/')
def administration(request):
    do something
    return something
```

Comment: it is a problem, because when you go back with the browser button, you will see some data for the last session before loging out. i want to block it like how django admin works

Comment: But django admin also doesn't block it: if you are on an admin page, log out, and press the back button, you'll see the previous page and not the login screen. It's just the way browsers work.